# How do I convert 4 text files in to csv with 4 columns

Tags: csv, text

-File 1-
a
b
c

-File 2-
1
2
3

-File 3-
LA
SF
DC

-File 4-
red
blue
silver

I would like to achieve the following and have no idea of how...

a 1 LA red
b 2 SF blue
c 3 DC silver

Comment: Which language?

Comment: Either python, awk or even something simple in bash would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the Terminal:

```
paste file1 file2 | paste - file3 | paste - file4
```

If you want commas in between instead of tabs, use `paste -d,` everywhere instead.

Or add `| tr '\t' ','` at the end.

Comment: Wow, how did I not know about paste this whole time!! Its awesome. Having issues with paste -d... its dropping file1. working through that now. :)

Comment: Figured it out. after the -d you get to choose the delimiter of your choice... what a great tool. paste -d , file1 file2

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

data = [ [] for _ in range(4) ]
filenames = ["file_1.txt", "file_2.txt", "file_3.txt", "file_4.txt"]
for i in range(4):
    with open(filenames[i], 'r') as F:
        data[i] = F.readlines()
data = np.asarray(data)
with open("output.csv", 'w') as F:
    for i in range(4):
        F.write(','.join( s for s in data[:][i] ))
```

That should work

Comment: If you don't mind me asking.  Can you explain how this works?

Comment: First, you create a numpy array of four arrays. Then you define your list of filenames. After that, you read each file in succession and put the data in one of the arrays. After that, you output each line of the combined file by joining each column of data by commas and writing it to the .csv file. Note that the commas are important as they delimit the columns in CSV files

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. I got numpy installed. However I ran in to this issue: ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 8889 to array axis with dimension 0. Might you know what is causing the issue or how I would add dimension to the axis?

Comment: Okay, so that happens because numpy likes to work with arrays that have standard sizes. I'll edit my question so that it should work